# How can I find left and right directions associated with each zero for a MIMO transfer function?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

How can I find left and right directions associated with each zero for a MIMO transfer function?

Intia[image]

First it can be expressed in Smith-McMillan form and can find poles and zeros. Then how to find the "left and right directions associated with each zero" ?
In above image poles & zeros are found for the first transfer function.